# I got this error when I runned discord.js bot

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

**When I runned the bot I got this error**

```
C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Bot>node .
C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Bot\src\my_bot.js:8
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
                      ^

ReferenceError: Discord is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Bot\src\my_bot.js:8:23)
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)←[39m
←[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47←[39m
```

**my_bot.js**
https://sourceb.in/ZN42H2fCes

When I runned the bot I got this error .I have installed discord.js but still I am getting this error.I have runned the bot using ./src/my_bot.js too but it still doesn't work. Thank you for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a simple solution.
Discord is not defined.

You could instead define `Collection` to require `discord.js` as follows:

```
const { Client, Collection } = require('discord.js');
```

And from there, you can replace said line with:

```
client.commands = new Collection();
```

#### Final Code

https://sourceb.in/rzMp8tSbJX